# What is the relationship between Loop Quantum Gravity and Conformal Cyclic Cosmology?

Tags: cosmology, loop-quantum-gravity

I have heard/read of both of these "theories" or concepts by Roger Penrose (et al.?) - pardon my possible misuse of the word "theory".
Is CCC just one possible model of the universe based on the underlying theory of loop quantum gravity? Or is it something entirely different altogether, something which may not even rely on LCG?

Comment: what gave you that impression? there is no Loop in the wiki article on CCC and no CCC on the loop quantum gravity article ?

Comment: They are pretty different, with no link that I know of.

Comment: @anna v: Both were developed by Roger Penrose, afaiu. Both somehow try to model/explain physical reality on a grand scale. So I thought there might be some connecting thoughts. I wonder how there wouldn't be any.

Comment: @ Anders Sandberg: Thanks. This is a clear answer. Why make it  a comment?

Comment: Okay, it seems I was misinformed and QLG was developed by Amithabha Sen, Abhay Ashtekar, Carlo Rovelli, Lee Smolin and others, and that only the concept of spin  networks developed by  Penrose was somehow an important ingredient.